# Automation of angular build and integrating with spring boot application

Tags: angular

Automate the build process for angular, spring boot application

Hi,

I need to automate the build process, currently, we are deploying manually using "ng build" command, after getting the dist folder. placing the same in spring boot application.

Finally, building .war using maven.

please help me in automating the above process in Jenkins server

Comment: What build tools do you use? Gradle?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am in search of open source tools for automating, waiting for some inputs to try